# tlmgr update fails as a cron job

Tags: updating, tlmgr

I am using the following command to update my TeXLive 2019 installation on Ubuntu (installed it from CTAN, not packages) on a weekly basis to keep my packages reasonably up to date:

```
sudo /usr/local/texlive/2019/bin/x86_64-linux/tlmgr update --self -all
```

This works as expected, even when called using a shell script (sudo /root/bin/updatetexlive):

```
#!/bin/bash

/usr/local/texlive/2019/bin/x86_64-linux/tlmgr update --self -all
```

However, when I invoke this using cron (sudo crontab -e):

```
20 23 * * sun /root/bin/updatetexlive
```

(Every Sunday at 11:20 PM.)

I get the cryptic error:

> Unable to download the checksum of the remote TeX Live database, but
>   found a local copy, so using that.
>
> You may want to try specifying an explicit or different CTAN mirror,
>   or maybe you need to specify proxy information if you're behind a
>   firewall; see the information and examples for the -repository option
>   at https://tug.org/texlive/doc/install-tl.html (and in the output of
>   install-tl --help).
>
> tlmgr: package repository
>   http://ctan.math.utah.edu/systems/texlive/tlnet (not verified: u nknown)
>   tlmgr: saving backups to /usr/local/texlive/2019/tlpkg/backups

As a matter of general rule, when something fails in cron when it works on the command line, usually an environment variable related to the calling  shell is at fault. So, I looked in my list of export's on the commandline, and found three possible variables. I set them in the crontab:

```
PATH="/usr/local/texlive/2019/bin/x86_64-linux:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin"
TEXMFDIST="/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist"
SHELL=/bin/bash
```

However, I still get the error above. How do I make tlmgr run as a cron job?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a proxy issue. Needed to set the http_proxy, http_proxy and ftp_proxy variables to the right values (in crontab), and it worked.

```
http_proxy=http://10.22.31.1:3128
https_proxy=https://10.22.31.1:3128
ftp_proxy=ftp://10.22.31.1:3128
```

Note that you have to specify the full URL for this to work.

Updating your tex database on a regular basis using a cron job should be the recommended standard operating procedure on Linux/Unix/Mac OSX installations.

Comment: On single user machines I try and be very careful about when I update TeX. If I have a deadline on Monday, I sure as heck don't want to update and break something on Sunday night.